# Sum values in the column, if another column data are equal

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to analyze the data with >10K rows.
It contains 2 columns. 1st column has ID number. This number is repeating from row to row different times.
Columns 2 has just numbers, which I want to sum up if value in column 1 is the same.

***For example: Image showing example attached.***

[image]

First, what I did - is filtered from A/Z and trying with cycle find out qty of repeating items:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim row, B, i, col As Long
Dim H As Worksheet

Set H = Sheets("Sheet1")

H.Activate

row = H.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For B = 4 To row
  i = 1
  j = H.Cells(B, 2).Value
  If H.Cells(B, 1).Value = H.Cells(B + 1, 1).Value Then
    
  i = i + 1
```

.....

Result of sum I want to place in the last row where same IDs are matching. And after all, delete those not required ones.

Appreciate in advance any help on this.

Comment: Why are you not using `SUMIF`?

Comment: I dont know how to sumif them, as criteria is unknown. They just have a equal values in column 1. I uploaded the picture, where example is shown. Thanks

Comment: You can do this pretty simply with either a pivot table or with power query

Comment: Post your data to post body with screenshot.

Comment: With Pivot its not really handy, because this report is being updated every day, and I want to run this analysis let's say, every week, by pressing button only.

Comment: That's what the Update/Refresh button is for, or you can just create a command button that mimics it.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. I think I can record a macro for it with creating a pivot.

Comment: Ron, I'm wondering also if it will be easier to use Power Query? I'm totally dumb in this

Comment: Power Query is certainly more flexible.  But for your task, I'd think either would work well.  And if you utilize a **Table** for your Pivot table data source, you don't have to recreate the pivot table each time; you can just add data and then Refresh the table.  With Power Query, it will create a table if your data is not in a table.  Again, just a refresh is all that's needed if you change your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete rows after summing then `VBA` is best. Otherwise you can achieve out using excel formulas only. First you need to extract unique value from first column. Then you need to sum values based on unique values you extracted. So if you have `Office365` then use `UNIQUE()` function to extract unique values like below.

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A14)
```

Then use `SUMIF()` to sum for these unique values.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$14,D2,$B$2:$B$14)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a Pivot Table.

Since you will be updating/refreshing the data:

- Select a cell in your data table and `Insert/Table`
- Then, depending on your Excel version:  Summarize with Pivot Table (or similar)
- Note that there is no need to sort the data.

Then you merely drag

- ID to the Rows area
- Value to the Values area

  - If your values are numeric, it should default to Sum of Values
- Rename / Format / decide on totals and subtotals, etc.

To refresh, the data after changing it, you merely need to select `Data/Refresh`, or you can create a command button to do the same.

[image]